# Organization of measures and folders in SSAS

Tags: excel, ssas, business-intelligence, cube, measure

Where can I organize the folders and measures that are visible to the users? I would think that this is done somewhere in SSAS.

[image: 1]

I have received a request to alter the current structure seen above in Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved on visual studio.Open the SSAS project and then select the .cube on the solution explorer. Then on the left side you will see the hierarchy of Dimensions and measures. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSUIY.png)
 You can select a measure, calculation or attribute you can view the properties and give the object a display folder (Properties->Advanced->DisplayFolder=FolderX). 
In order to add a measure or an attribute in a nested folder: FolderParent\FolderChild
add a measure or an attribute in multiple folders: FolderX;FolderY

Comment: Thanks for the answer to @krynil's question but I don't think you covered setting display folders or visibility or even perspectives. It doesn't seem like you answered the question. Do you want to edit your answer to elaborate on these topics?

Comment: Setting display folders and visibility is more the case here, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for improving the answer

Comment: Is there really a DisplayFolder property for an attribute? I am not able to find this in SSDT 2012